# Wordpress wp-config.php

Tags: php, wordpress, bash

Is there any way to fully and manually install Wordpress via a script / CLI?

I've tried to configure wp-config.php to do it, but I can't seem to be able to pass the language selection page.

I've tried to manually download the language package and add a line to the config file, as follows (assume sudo where needed, as well as the correct path to everything):

- wget https://downloads.wordpress.org/translation/core/5.5.1/en_GB.zip
- unzip wordpress-5.5.1-en_GB.zip
- sed -i $'That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing./idefine('WPLANG', 'en_GB');

As for the following steps, below in images, any idea as to how I can achieve a full installation or where could I find more information regarding my problem?

This server is running on a VM (VirtualBox), powered by CentOS 8.

Images of the necessary steps in the browser:

[image: install.php]

[image: install.php?step=1]

[image: install.php?step=2]

[image: wp-login.php]

[image: wp-admin]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, the nifty: `wp cli`, from here: https://wp-cli.org/

```
wp core download
wp config create --dbname=YOURDBNAME --dbuser=YOURDBUSER --dbpass=DBPASS
wp core install --url=http://www.example.com --title='My WP Site' --admin_user=ADMINUSERNAME --admin_password=CLEARTEXTPASS --admin_email=ADMINEMAIL --skip-email
```

And you are done :)

Answer (score 0):

WP loading calls [`is_blog_installed()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_blog_installed/) which checks a number of things and decides whether to show the install screens.

From the looks of it, you must set the `siteurl` in wp_options table to load the site instead of the installer

This could be relevant as well: https://wordpress.org/support/article/automated-installation/